# How to create ceiling light effect in three.js that overlays the rest of the DOM elements transparently?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js

I want to create an effect with three.js that acts as a ceiling light, casting a light over the rest of the DOM elements in a realistic looking way.

So ideally it would be like a light bulb on the top right corner and that point is the brightest part of the page, and the rest of the page are dimmed based on distance from the light.

I am very new to three.js but my approach so far is using a point light over a plane mesh. However, the plane mesh is not transparent, so it actually covers the DOM elements behind the canvas.

Is there anyway the point light can still work with the plane being transparent?

I added orbit controls in the following codesandbox so that you could move the plane around to understand the 3d space.

Thanks

https://codesandbox.io/s/canvas-lighting-experiment-wip-3p9im?file=/src/Canvas.component.jsx

Comment: Understood, well, it's fine that the DOM elements aren't affected. But is the effect of the lighting achievable? Where it starts very bright and it dims into the distance, as in the dim areas would be transparent to show the DOM elements underneath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have to add `opacity: 0` to your test, and it works

```
const material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    wireframe: false,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    opacity: 0
  })
```

[image]

Anyway, IMHO and if you allow me to provide you an alternative and much simpler solution, this is like shooting a fish in a barrel, as this can be achieved directly with CSS styles in one single line of a class

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    #grad1 { 
         height: 200px;
         background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom left, 
         rgba(255,232,174,1), rgba(255,232,174,0)); }
    </style>
 </head>
 <body>
     <div id="grad1"></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

**EDITED** based on your second question on your comment, you are creating a squared `PlaneBufferGeometry`, if you want to fill in the full page you will need to calculate dynamically the size, depending the position of the transparent plane in the scene and to the camera based on the aspect ratio you are already calculatin, but basically you need to change the size of the `PlaneBufferGeometry`, check out what happens when you change to 5 and 9 the size of the plane geometry

```
 const geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(5, 9, 1, 1)
```

Comment: Wow thanks! Could you show how to make the canvas square fill the viewport's height and width?

Comment: Please, mark the question as answer accepted if it solved your initial problem, this way will also help other users to know it was the solution.

Comment: Done, could you help answer my previous question?

Comment: Just saw your edit. I had the same idea of ur suggestion, how would you dynamically change the size of the mesh? The lighting should always stay in the top right corner btw...

Comment: Hi @bee-wai, I just replied in the other question you posted with more detail. I hope it solves you issues. Let me know if you need any more help